# error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, npm, npm-scripts

There is some problem regarding the promise which I cant figure out, so when I type in something for example 'pizza' in the search bar and hit search.Console output gives me this error  TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

I tried to look for any misspelling but couldn't find anything.

it's my github repo: https://github.com/damianjnc/forkifyApp

Anyone can see what causing the error and how to debug it?

Comment: Please post the code you're having trouble with in the question. That way if someone in the future has a similar question, and your GitHub repo isn't accessible, they can see the problematic code. Also a lot of contributors here (myself included) would prefer the code be in the question as well.

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets in the question itself. Code in external links or images are not allowed here in StackOverflow.

Comment: Line 26 index.js I would console.log(state.search.result) I suspect this is not an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be mistaken but I feel like this (in SearchView.js):

```
export const renderResults = recipes => {
    recipes.forEach(renderRecipe);
};
```

should be like the following:

```
export const renderResults = recipes => {
    recipes.forEach(recipe => renderRecipe(recipe));
};
```

Please let me know if this helps. Cheers!

Comment: it worked, thanks man, I spent like 5 hrs trying to sort it out yesterday, can I buy you a cup of coffee or something?

Comment: Haha cheers man, thanks for the offer. In the future, providing code as part of the question instead of providing a github repo link could be better by the way. The link can become deprecated or the repo can be private in the future, meaning other people who experience a similar problem wouldn't be able to reach the problem/solution. :)